# Undefined variable : this

Tags: php

Inside the method i got this line:

`if ($db == null && is_object($this) && isset($this->db)) $db = $this->db;`

And I got the error above.

I am using PHP 5.2 and have been searching everywhere but seems I'm the only one having this problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: does your `$db` var is protected or public ? also where you are going to use above condition ?

Comment: Is your function inside a class?

Comment: In a regular method there is no way that $this is not defined. Are you sure it's a regular object method inside a class, and the method is not static?

Comment: Hi @samitha thanks for the lightning response. It is public. But I don't think the error is coming from $this->db but rather is_object($this) because I tried omitting the $this->db and error is still there for the is_object($this) line.

Comment: @HüseyinBABAL yes it is inside a class

Comment: Could you please provide code of full class?

Comment: Inside *what* method? How are you calling it?

Comment: @WolfgangStengel ----  class Base { public $db = null; ... and then the public function that has that problem line above.

Comment: Why bother checking for `is_object($this)` anyway? It'll always return true (unless this is a static method), but you haven't said. Post the entire class in your question - we need _far_ more context

Comment: @jnroche can you post extract error here?

Comment: I think you have another problem, see [here](http://ideone.com/NZEt1I) there is no problem in your case

Comment: @samitha : Notice: Undefined variable: this in C:\xampp\htdocs\xx\xx\include\base.class.php on line 141

Comment: And line 141 is the line in your question? Post your full function

Comment: Where is exact issue?

Comment: @HüseyinBABAL no sorry, i have deleted my comment. The error is not for db but variable 'this'

Comment: and yes it is called as a static method, this is how it is called somewhere in the code calling it ---> Base::Update();

Comment: But there is not `$db` variable actually. But `$this` always exists. Because it refers current class. I think you have defined a variable called `$this` somewhere in your code

Comment: Why do you call `$this` in static method?

Comment: @HüseyinBABAL yes it refers to current class, and no there are no other variable defined as $this in the class. the $db variable is passed as an argument to the function.

Comment: Do not call `$this` in static method. If you tell what you trying to do actually, I can help.

Comment: @HüseyinBABAL the function itself is not declared as static function though it was called by way of static referencing, for e.g. Base::Update();

Comment: Could you please share your class and function structure? We cannot help like this way

Comment: @HüseyinBABAL how can i attach it here?

Comment: You can put it here http://ideone.com/

Comment: @HüseyinBABAL http://ideone.com/1GLua6 there you go, it is in line 141

Comment: But, I am not getting your error http://ideone.com/1qyPn8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried a similar code at 
http://codepad.viper-7.com/dQLeXu
and I got the same error as you do. But my code is outside of a class. is your method static method or instance method?

Comment: the function itself is not declared as static function though it was called by way of static referencing, for e.g. Base::Update();

Comment: I have update the example at http://codepad.viper-7.com/mbyTxo
I think your error is due to called instance method in static way.

Comment: I am accepting yours as an answer. I may have to revamp the entire code that uses this static method. This was an old code passed on to me.